# Is there a curtain material that can act as an air barrier but lets light through?

Tags: insulation, windows, curtain-rail

I have an uninsulated and drafty bay window wall that I can't insulate or seal so want to put floor length curtains.  However, all the "thermal" curtains I've found online also are blackout curtains that cut off all light.

I am mainly concerned with winter heating and want to let light in, and only want to create an air block.  I also want it to look like residential curtains and not some industrial barrier (so I won't use shower curtains for instance).

Comment: Is it an air barrier that you're after? Or an air barrier plus insulation? The insulation is a deal breaker with letting light through.

Comment: Shrink wrap and caulking rather than expecting the curtains to do it...

Comment: @keshlam And, if one is the prankster type, leave a plate of cookies in the bay on the opposite side of the shrink film barrier.

Comment: You've asked a bit of any [XY question](http://xyproblem.info), about your proposed solution rather than the actual problem. I suggest revision to expand scope of solutions. Frankly, I'm not sure how curtains would even help. Convection would just keep the air circulating.

Comment: Insulating curtains can help in summer, by reflecting sunlight. Less so during winter, though they may at least redirect drafts to floor level where you don't notice them as much. I use them, but not asy primary solution.

Comment: And shrink wrap, or glass panels, also turn your bay window into a rather nice display case.

Comment: I will second the shrink wrap(window insulation kits) for the drafts.  They are clear so lets all the light while stopping drafts(if done right).

Answer (score 1):

As many comments refer to, some form of shrink plastic wrap can work well with drafty windows (Such as Frost King or Duck brand are the ones I've used most).

Things to consider:

- Depending on the size you may have to tape pieces together.
- Depending on necessary durability you may need to go for thicker Polyethylene Sheeting.  They can be partially to completely opaque but if durability is a necessity, then that may be your best option.

Comment: We used to by Frost King for the film and ignore their tape, getting 3M tape separately, rather than buying the 3M kit (more expensive for the film+tape than the less costly film and the good quality tape this way.)

Comment: There was one year where 3M botched the tape formulation, at least in the batch that reached the Northeast. But, yes, normally I consider them one of the more trustworthy manufacturers.